# Check if there is 0 rows in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this line of code that i want to return true/false if no "Sensor" exists.

I know for sure that i have 1 sensor with no data, and then i want to add data to it if it doesn't have data already.

```
var dataExsist = Context.SensorLogs
                        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.SensorId == sensor.SensorId);
```

It will find all the sensors that have data, but not the one without data.

I tried with `.Count` to see if it would show 0, but it doesn't.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to use is .Any();

```
using System.Linq;

bool doesExists = Context.SensorLogs.Any(a => a.SensorId == sensor.SensorId);

bool doesNotExists = !Context.SensorLogs.Any(a => a.SensorId == sensor.SensorId);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 

i tried the following, but dident get any "True" response back.

     bool doesNotExists = !Context.SensorLogs.Any(a => a.SensorId == sensor.SensorId);
                    if (doesNotExists == true )
                    {
                        firstTimeData = true;
                        Console.WriteLine(doesNotExists + " TRUE");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        firstTimeData = false;
                        Console.WriteLine(doesNotExists +  " FALSE");
                    }

Comment: weird then the id you're passing is actually existing on your database. have you tried like checking the database first? or probably query the data first like var sensorLogs = Context.SensorLogs.ToList(); to check the list of data and compare if the id you passing is existing on that list. but yea the fastest way is to check manually in the database.

Comment: Yes i checked the database than there is no logs with sensorId 58. But a sensor with id 58 exsist, but just no logs. So it shuld give me something there.

Comment: When we use count inside database for this sensor we get the count 0. But this number we cant get with the .Count method in the code when we loop over all sensors.

Comment: can you try to hard code it instead of using an object like a hardcode Context.SensorLogs.Any(a => a.SensorId == 58) or probably try a number that does exists

Comment: Yes i tried hardcoding it. But when i console log all sensors. It will only show 58 if there is allready data inside it. So i think mabye the problem could be somewhere else.